# How do I generate RTD documentation for offline reading?

Tags: python, documentation

Is there any convenient way to read & access the project-documentation of a Python packages -  f.e. like a ReadTheDocs-documentation (https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ for bs4 in this case)- offline?

I know that there is a pydoc-server, docstrings and so on. However, these do not include the full documentation like tutorials, quickstarts etc. Is there an equivalent feature in Python like the vignettes in R?

Comment: You can download the document in three format at ReadTheDocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation on RtD is generated using [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/). Larger Python packages will have the files required to generate this documentation in their source archive and usually available via `make doc` or in a specific format via e.g. `make html` or `make pdf`. For BS4 specifically, the makefile is under `docs/`, and running `make help` will show which further targets are available.